# What Alt.Net Solutions have you ported to Mono / Linux?

Tags: linux, mono, alt.net

I hope to gain insight on what has already been accomplished, and what pitfalls you experienced along the way.

---

UPDATE:

From [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Software), there are numerous applications listed such as Unity 3d, SWFDotNet, VistaDB, and even [paint-mono(Paint.Net)](http://code.google.com/p/paint-mono/) but there are no OR/M's or IoC listed.

Answer (score 3):

Just to list the big names - Spring.Net and NHibernate work on Mono. Check the bugzilla for bugreports and fixes (all of the should be incorporated in recent releases, such basic problems are now mostly gone).

Comment: It sounds like I have to go to each project and research.  I was hoping for something ohlo where I could browse.  Thanks.

Comment: Generally you can assume things do work, until they don't. Then you can go looking for solutions/bugreports.